# Unity Crafting System List with Multiple Properties

Tags: unity-game-engine

This seems like a very basic question, but I can't seem to figure it out. I am trying to make a crafting system in unity. I made an inventory system with an items that are scriptable objects storing the name of the item as a string and amount of the item as an int. To add the crafting system, I am trying to make recipe scriptable objects that hold a list of items, the amount needed per item, and the output item of the recipe. My code for the recipes is as follows:

```
public class Recipe : ScriptableObject
{
    new public string name = "New Recipe";
    public List<Item> requiredItems;
    public Item outputItem;
}
```

The problem is that I want to have each item in the list of required items have their own amount which I can set, but I can't seem to get it to work. I can only make it so that there is one amount variable for all the items or I have to make a new list for the amounts of the items, which I don't think is a good idea. Is there any way I can contain both the item and amount in the same list?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making a struct that holds the name and amount of the reguired item. To find the referenced item at runtime make a singleton manager and hold references to all items in that manager. This way you overcome the limitation of always getting only one item out of a recipe at the same time as well (e.g. 5 sticks from 1 log).

```
public struct CraftingItem
{
    public string itemName;
    public int itemAmount;
}

public class Recipe : ScriptableObject
{
    new public string name = "New Recipe";
    public List<CraftingItem> requiredItems;
    public CraftingItem outputItem;
}
```

Comment: great answer, I oversaw the fact that the author was talking about scriptable objects:) I think alternatively to a struct one could also create a class

Comment: Yes, with a class it would work basically the same. I chose a struct for the simple reason that I see this CraftingItem to be a pure data container that is immutable.